# Transform local variable and generate map for multiple resources

Tags: terraform

I'm not getting my head to find a solution for the following scenario:

I've the following local structure (simplified)

```
locals {    
    groups = {
        group1 = { 
            option1 = "Option1 Value Group1"
            option2 = [ "option2_item1", "option2_item1" ]
            option3 = { option3_key1 = "value1", option3_key2 = "value2" }
        }
        group2 = {
            option1 = "Option1 Value Group2"
            option2 = [ "option2_item1" ]
            option3 = { option3_key1 = "value1", option3_key2 = "value2" }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to transform it as follows:

```
[
   {
      result1 = "group1"               # First Key of groups variable
      result2 = "Option1 Value Group1" # String of option1
      result3 = "option2_item1"        # First item in list option2
      result4 = "value1"               # Value of first key in option3
      result5 = "value2"               # Value of second key in option3
   }
   {
      result1 = "group1"               
      result2 = "Option1 Value Group1" 
      result3 = "option2_item2"        # First item in list option2
      result4 = "value1"               
      result5 = "value2"               
   }
   {
      result1 = "group2"               # 2nd Key of groups variable
      result2 = "Option1 Value Group2" 
      result3 = "option2_item2"        
      result4 = "value1"               
      result5 = "value2"               
   }
 ]
```

I've already tried for_each and "for ... in" variants but I'm not getting any closer to the desired solution.

I would really appreciate somebody to guide me into the right direction.

Thank you very much

Comment: Please add what have you tried already.

Comment: "for_each and "for ... in" variants " - where is TF code that you tried and what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a huge step further now.

I now used multiple for...in loops

```
locals {

  groups = {
    group1 = {
      option1 = "Option1 Value Group1"
      option2 = [ "option2_item1", "option2_item1" ]
      option3 = [ "option3_item1", "option3_item1" ]
    }
    group2 = {
            option1 = "Option1 Value Group2"
            option2 = [ "option2_item1" ]
            option3 = [ "option3_item1", "option3_item2" ]
        }
  }

  helper_groups = flatten([ for group, group_values in local.groups:
              [ for option2_value in group_values.option2:
                [ for option3_value in group_values.option3:
                  {
                    result1 = group
                    result2 = group_values.option1
                    result3 = option2_value
                    result4 = option3_value
                  }
                ]
              ]
  ])
}


output "list_of_maps" {
  value = local.helper_groups
}
```

Now it should be easy to switch option3 to map as indicated in the original post.